# Perl/awk/bash: multiply and sum values putting values inline instead original text

Tags: bash, awk, perl

I have a text like this:

```
;---------------------------------------
JOURNEY_ARRAY_01
    .BYTE <JOURNEY_00
    .BYTE <JOURNEY_01
;---------------------------------------
JOURNEY_ARRAY_03
    .BYTE JOURNEY_01-JOURNEY_00
    .BYTE JOURNEY_02-JOURNEY_01
;---------------------------------------
JOURNEY_00                              ; From 00 to 01
    .BYTE $01, $01, $01, $03, $01, $01, $03, $01
    .BYTE $03, $01, $03, $01, $03, $01, $03, $01
    .BYTE $03, $03, $01, $03, $03, $03, $03, $00
    .BYTE $03, $03, $00, $03, $00, $03, $00, $03
    .BYTE $00, $03, $00, $03, $03, $00, $03, $03
    .BYTE $00, $03, $03, $03, $03, $03, $03, $01
    .BYTE $03, $03, $01, $03, $03, $01, $03
;---------------------------------------
JOURNEY_01                              ; From 00 to 04
    .BYTE $01, $01, $01, $03, $01, $01, $03, $01
    .BYTE $03, $01, $03, $01, $03, $01, $03, $01
    .BYTE $03, $03, $01, $03, $01, $03, $01, $01
    .BYTE $03, $01, $03, $01, $01, $01, $01, $01
    .BYTE $02, $01, $01, $01, $02, $01, $01, $01
    .BYTE $02, $01, $01, $01, $01, $01, $01, $01
    .BYTE $01, $01, $01
;---------------------------------------
```

I need to take each numeric value after ".BYTE" and for every 4 values do this:
 - first value do nothing;
 - second value multiply *4;
 - third value multiply *16;
 - fourth value multiply *64;
sum these 4 values and put the result, in hex format prefixed with "$" instead of the four original values.
If values after ".BYTE" aren't multiply of 4, or are minus than 4, missing values should be calculated as zeroes.
For example:

```
.BYTE $01, $01, $01, $03, $01, $01, $03, $01
```

should become:

```
.BYTE $57, 5D
```

because:

```
03*1 = 3 +
01*4 = 4 +
01*16 = 16 +
01*64 = 64 = 87 = $57
and
01*1 = 1 +
03*4 = 12 +
01*16 = 16 +
01*64 = 64 = 93 = $5D
```

Values not presents should be calculated as zero in the maths...
Obviously, other text should not be changed.

Any one?

Comment: Can you show us your workings so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `sed` plus `gawk` (GNU awk) solution performs the requested task:

```
 sed -e '/ .BYTE/{s/\$/0x/g;s/,//g}' INPUTFILE.txt | 
     gawk --non-decimal-data '/.BYTE.*0x/{ printf ".BYTE $%x, $%x\n",
       ($5+$4*4+$3*16+$2*64 ) , ($9+$8*4+$7*16+$6*64) };!/.BYTE.*0x/{print}'
```

The `sed` call replaces `$01` with `0x01` and delete commas in the `.BYTE` lines which need to be modified. The awk call then recognize the hexadecimal numbers, perform the calculations and outputs the result for these lines. Other lines are simply copied to the output.

The pattern work for the given example but may need to be modified if there are other `.BYTE` line formats used.

The command assumes that there are exactly two blocks of 4 numbers each line.
So it outputs for the last line of the input

```
.BYTE $54, $0
```